# How to develop apps that measure data usage for other apps using flutter

Tags: android, flutter

It's my first time developing an app, so I don't know what to do.

I'm going to develop an app that collects network data usage of other apps on flutter.

I've used examples of "**usage_stats**" and "**app_usage**."
The data you wanted didn't come out.

The data I want is

1. Network data used by other apps
2. Name of "**Activity**" activated in other apps

I'd like to develop it for Android, so would it be possible on flutter?
Or should we develop it with Android Native?

Thank you.